# EdgeNGram: Error instantiating class: 'org.apache.lucene.analysis.ngram.EdgeNGramFilterFactory'

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I've set up Solr, so far everything's working just dandy, but now I wanted to add the EdgeNGram functionality to my searches. However, as soon as I throw it into my schema.xml, it starts throwing the error:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
Could not load conf for core collection1: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] 
fieldType "text_en_splitting": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: 
Error instantiating class: 'org.apache.lucene.analysis.ngram.EdgeNGramFilterFactory'. 
Schema file is /opt/solr/server/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml
```

The relevant schema part looks like this:

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
```

The configuration of the rest of the fieldType is fine as I've tested it rather extensively. It's just adding this line that throws the error.

Now, I've done some looking around, and usually, these errors mean that there's a .jar that's missing (at least according to the other two questions posted on here, not relating to NGram specifically though). So I went ahead and digged up lucene-analyzers-common.jar and explicitly added it in my solrconfig.xml, like so:

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="lucene-analyzers-common-\d.*\.jar" />
```

No luck. I know the path is fine though, I included the mysql_connector just this way. Anyways, I grew pretty tired of this error, so I went ahead and included every single .jar that I could dig up:

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-.*\.jar" />
```

Nope.jpg

Of course, all of this was accompanied by many bin/solr stop -all and starts, all of them still serving me that pretty, red banner in the Solr Admin. I'm on Solr 5.0.0

Help?

Comment: I have just the same problem as you, found out that the attribute isn't working. 
Small hint: You don't have to restart Solr every time, it is sufficient to Reload the appropriate core in the core admin.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, this is awkward, but it's a typical thing to happen to me. Not 5 minutes after I posted this question, I made the error go away [note that I say "error go away", I didn't say "I solved it", because I haven't tested it completely yet].

Anyways, in my filter tag, you see that `side="front"` tag? Yeah, bad idea apparently. It's odd though, because I found that in the apache docs: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory, I didn't make it up or anything.

Can anyone explain that?

Comment: It was marked as deprecated in Solr 4.4 and was removed with 5.0. So it is basically a bug in the documentation. Look here instead: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-EdgeN-GramFilter

Comment: Damn, that's pretty annoying. Stupid documentation. Congrats for finding the issue though :)

Comment: Yep. Just saw in logs `Caused by: Unknown parameters: {side=front}`